# NodeJS: Convert table string (with \n \r and \t) to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have data coming out of an API that looks like this:

```
'Type1\tCode\tPrice\tQuantity\r\n4X-US0U-R114\tB004P2NG0K\t37.99\t15\r\nGC-NP0Y-XPOA\tB007KAYCGQ\t150.00\t4\r\nRL-E0ZD-16G1\tB016FWZDO4\t28.00\t\r\n'
```

How can I convert this into JSON? (I'm using NodeJS if there are any easy methods for this)

My first thought was to replace the tab characters, then run the output into Node's [csvtojson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson), like:

```
var str = 'Type1\tCode\tPrice\tQuantity\r\n4X-US0U-R114\tB004P2NG0K\t37.99\t15\r\nGC-NP0Y-XPOA\tB007KAYCGQ\t150.00\t4\r\nRL-E0ZD-16G1\tB016FWZDO4\t28.00\t\r\n'
str = str.replace(/\t/g, ' ');

converter.fromString(data, function(err,result){
      console.log(result);
});
```

However, this results in malformed data, like this:

```
[ { 'type  code  price  quantity': '4X-US0U-R114  B004P2NG0K  37.99  15' },
  { 'type  code  price  quantity': 'GC-NP0Y-XPOA  B007KAYCGQ  150.00  4' },
  { 'type  code  price  quantity': 'RL-E0ZD-16G1  B016FWZDO4  28.00' } ]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the final output? 2d array? array with objects?

Comment: @epascarello Edited it into my post

Comment: seems weird to want it like that...

Comment: @epascarello I don't want it like that! That's what's currently being outputted by the CSV converter.

Comment: What is the final output you want?? That is what I am trying to figure out so I can help you.

Comment: @epascarello `[{type: '4x......', code: 'B004...', price: 37.99, quantity: 15}, {....}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. So it is basically a split to get rows.
2. Remove the first row to get titles
3. Than loop over the rows
4. Split them up into cells
5. And iterate over the cells and psuh them into an object
6. And put the object into an array

The basic idea:

```
var str = 'Type1\tCode\tPrice\tQuantity\r\n4X-US0U-R114\tB004P2NG0K\t37.99\t15\r\nGC-NP0Y-XPOA\tB007KAYCGQ\t150.00\t4\r\nRL-E0ZD-16G1\tB016FWZDO4\t28.00\t\r\n'
var rows = str.split(/\r\n/g);
var title = rows.shift().split(/\t/g);
var altered = rows.reduce( function(arr, cur) {
    var x = {};
    if(cur.length){
        var parts = cur.split(/\t/g);    
        parts.map( function(v,i){
            x[title[i]] = v;
        } );
        arr.push(x);
    }
    return arr;
}, [] );
```

Comment: As in the OP I'm using Node, not jQuery, so `$.trim()` won't work here

Comment: Left that in by mistake when debugging when I had an extra index

Comment: Cool. In Node, this leaves `\r` in the `quantity` property of each object, doesn't seem to happen in the console. Might need a simple `.replace(/\r/g, '')` or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can split your array by `\n\r`, `\t` and then map/reduce it:

```
var data = 'Type1\tCode\tPrice\tQuantity\r\n4X-US0U-R114\tB004P2NG0K\t37.99\t15\r\nGC-NP0Y-XPOA\tB007KAYCGQ\t150.00\t4\r\nRL-E0ZD-16G1\tB016FWZDO4\t28.00\t\r\n';

var arr = data.trim().split('\r\n').map(function(row) {
    return row.split('\t');
}); // 2 - dimensional array

var headers = arr.shift(); // first row are table headers

var result = arr.map(function(row) {
    return row.reduce(function(obj, cell, i) {
        obj[headers[i]] = cell;
        return obj;
    }, {}); // map each row to object with headers as keys
});

console.log(result);
```

The output is in form:

```
[
    {
        'Type1': '4X-US0U-R114',
        'Code': 'B004P2NG0K',
        'Price': '37.99',
        'Quantity': '15'
    },
    {
        'Type1': 'GC-NP0Y-XPOA',
        'Code': 'B007KAYCGQ',
        'Price': '150.00',
        'Quantity': '4'
    },
    // ...
]
```

Comment: Ah, very smart. +1 for not making me rely on a CSV converter!

Comment: Actually, this has an error - the last object is malformed

Comment: @Jascination right, I forgot to trim the data. see update